# When using preg_replace on a variable in an array, the variable doesn't reflect preg_replace changes

Tags: php

I can't figure out what in the world is going wrong with my code.

Problem:
I'm getting results from a mysql DB, one of the variables returned needs to be run through preg_replace, the `preg_replace()` works just fine when I echo it out, but when I try to put that variable into the array, it doesn't reflect the `preg_replace()` changes.

```
$bl = array(
    'skills' => array()
);

if ($result = $db->query($queryStmt)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        extract($row);
        $newdesc = preg_replace("/\<[^>]+\)/","",$Desc);
        $sk = array(
            'desc' => $newdesc
        );
        array_push($bl['skills'], $sk);
    }
};

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($bl, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$db = NULL;
```

So again, if I echo the $newdesc variable before the array code, it displays properly, but when the array is echo'd out at the end of the script, it doesn't.

Edit:
Someone requested the `echo` response, if I echo out $newdesc this string: 
MP Regeneration  3 Bow skills used at every blow mentality may be eligible for as much as 3 each additional (but does not apply to a range type)

simply echos out as this:
MP Regeneration 3 Bow skills used at every blow mentality may be eligible for as much as 3 each additional (but does not apply to a range type)

And the code now reflects this:

```
$bl = array(
    'skills' => array()
);

if ($result = $db->query($queryStmt)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        extract($row);
        $newdesc = preg_replace("/\<[^>]+\)/","",$Desc);
        echo $newdesc;
        $sk = array(
            'desc' => $newdesc
        );
        array_push($bl['skills'], $sk);
    }
};

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($bl, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$db = NULL;
```

Edit again:
See answer for solution!

Comment: This code doesn't seem sane to me. The if and else both do the exact same thing. Did you trim parts of the code? Did you maybe remove the part that causes the bug?

Comment: Sorry, there's tons more variables that go into the array I just deleted them for clarity. I edited my question to reflect the code without the if statement, the bug still happens.

Comment: Try it without `extract()`.

Comment: Also, why not just `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Removed extract, problem still happens.  An example Desc string is like this "MP Regeneration <PAColor0xffe9bd23> 3 <PAOldColor>Bow skills used at every blow mentality may be eligible for as much as 3 each additional (but does not apply to a range type)"  I need to not only remove the <> but the text in between as well.

Comment: Could you update the question with the output of the two echo's you mention (before the array code, and at the end of the script)?

Comment: As @AbraCadaver said, try `strip_tags()` instead of regExp. Why did you make a function that exists?

Comment: Tons of information here : http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `strip_tags()` would just remove the <>, if you refer to my comment above I need to not only remove the <> but text that is inbetween them as well. I read the documentation and if `strip_tags()` does that, then I am missing it.

Comment: `"/\<[^>]+\)/"` doesn't match `<...>` but `<...)`

Comment: strip_tags remove all tags except if you define what do you want to preserve. Example: `$string = "<tag>asdf</tag>"; strip_tags($string);`  returns `asdf`. But `strip_tags($string, "<tag>")` returns `<tag>asdf</tag>`

Comment: Re "correct me if I'm wrong": Have you tried it? Have you read the examples in the documentation?

Comment: Maybe try using a pattern such as `(<.+>[^<>]+<.+>)`...

Comment: Welp, I learn something new every day.  `strip_tags()` works perfectly, feel like an idiot for not realizing it did that.  Seems I need to learn to pay attention more.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Kerblooy: Please post the solution (as an answer) so others might learn something as well :)

Comment: I think I've realised what was wrong in the first place. The preg_replace did nothing at all, because the regex is nonsense. The echo displayed the original string, but browsers obviously didn't display what look like html tags, so the OP thought the preg_replace was working. The array contains the actual text, and a var_dump shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the wonderful people in the comments, the solution to the problem was simply to use `strip_tags()` this my friends is a fine case of me being an idiot. Code is now this:

```
$bl = array(
    'skills' => array()
);

if ($result = $db->query($queryStmt)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $newdesc = strip_tags($row['Desc']);
        $sk = array(
            'desc' => $newdesc
        );
        array_push($bl['skills'], $sk);
    }
};

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($bl, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$db = NULL;
```

And it works perfectly.
I was making a function that already existed, read the documentation on `strip_tags()` for more info.
http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I can accept my own answer in two days time, will set alarm.  Thanks again!